# Accessing the default app domain

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

I am looking for a way to find the default [app domain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1094478/335858) in my process. Note than the current app domain may be different from the default one, for example when my code is running inside `NUnit`.

I know that I can list all the app domains in the process using [a COM interop trick shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388554/335858), and pick the one for which [`IsDefaultAppDomain()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.isdefaultappdomain.aspx) is `true`. However, this seems like a heavyweight solution.

Is there a way to get the default appdomain that does not require filtering all the domains, preferably without going through COM interop?

Comment: We've used the above COM Interop trick; however, I wonder if it's possible to just store the default app domain as a reference somewhere when your app starts (say in `Main`), and just look that up?

Comment: Yes, you can create a domain-neutral assembly, and in that assembly you can store a reference to the default AppDomain (in some static property).

Comment: @M.A.Hanin Would you mind illustrating this approach, or maybe add an answer that shows how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: After double checking, I found out that domain-neutral assemblies only share their code, not data (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058110/what-are-the-steps-for-making-domain-neutral-assemblies ), so my previous comment is invalid. Sorry :-(

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, the .NET framework does not support that. You would have to use the unmanaged solution which does support it.

Comment: An MSDN blog post dating back to 2007 says this: As I was showing isolation and unload-ability, I wanted to enumerate the AppDomain's in the current process. **Surprisingly there is no managed API in the BCL to show AppDomains.** Using Interop however, we can list the AppDomains. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jackg/archive/2007/06/11/enumerating-appdomains.aspx